# How to overload a method to support a params array and IEnumerable but interpret an IEnumerable always as IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, overloading, ienumerable

I wrote this overloaded method to allow the caller to pass whatever he/she wants (IEnumerable, List, HashSet, an array of Ts, but also multiple T values - comma separated):

```cs
public void Values<T>(IEnumerable<T> ts)
{
    Test(ts);
}

public void Values<T>(params T[] ts)
{
    Test(ts);
}

private void Test<T>(IEnumerable<T> ts)
{
    // I expect this method to receive an IEnumerable with at least 2
    // elements in it.
}
```

What I have not expected: The call `Values(new List<string> {"a", "b"})` actually **calls the 2nd method** rather than the first one. *I guess, that's because the params array is older than IEnumerable*

The problem in this case: My second method calls another method with an array that contains the list. That's not what I intended.

If I'd remove the first method, I won't be able to pass a hashset. If I'd remove the second method, I won't be able to pass the values comma separated.

What is a proper way to solve this dilemma?

1. If one value is passed and it implements IEnumerable, then I want to pass its values to the Test() method.
2. If one value is passed and it does not implement IEnumerable, then I want to pass that value within an IEnumerable or array to the Test() method.
3. If multiple values are passed, then I want to pass those values to the Test() method.

I experimented with generic constraints and ugly reflection code but haven't found any solution.

Comment: It would be nice if you modify question and provide different cases like in which case which methods need to call because when you said proper way solve dilemma then each line test method get called so it overall confusing.

Comment: You would only implement the second method. If you have a `HashSet` just use `ToList()` before calling it.

Comment: string implements IEnumerable, what would you want to happen if your method is called with a single string?

Comment: "I expect this method to receive an IEnumerable with at least 2 elements in it" Well, `new List<string>()` has no elements, so should `Values(new List<string>())` not work at all? Note: you can't tell if a collection has 2 elements or not at compile time.

Comment: "You would only implement the second method. If you have a HashSet just use ToList() before calling it." => I know that that's possible. But I'm writing a library and don't want the user to have to do that.

Comment: "has no elements, so should Values(new List<string>()) not work at all" => Ok, my example was bad. BTW: I check that during runtime.

Comment: "I guess, that's because the params array is older than IEnumerable" - no, it's because `T` is more "specific". With type inference fhe compiler will look at the static type of the parameter passed to it, in this case `List<>`. There's an overload that takes `IEnumerable` and one that takes `T`. The list, while implementing IEnumerable is not *statically typed* as such. There's an "exact match" for an arbitrary `T` and that's the overload that is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Either add `AsEnumerable()`, or explicitly specify the type of generics. And you will get a call to the desired method overload.

```
var list = new List<int>();

Values(list); // params

Values(list.AsEnumerable()); // IEnumerable
Values<int>(list); // IEnumerable
```

Comment: Thanks. But both suggestions are pretty much "The caller of the methods has to change something". So I ask myself: Is my implementation maybe bad? Is it maybe bad practice to overload a method how I did it?